# php __autoload() is not working

Tags: php

I haven't seen any error in my files but when I run my code it shows me the following error:

> Warning: require_once(Core.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\completed\inc\autoload.php on line 7
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'Core.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\completed\inc\autoload.php on line 7

My code is:

**classes/Core.php**

```
 <?php
  class Core {

   public function run() {
      ob_start();
      require_once(Url::getPage());
      ob_get_flush();
     }

}
```

**inc/autoload.php**

```
 <?php
 require_once('config.php');

function __autoload($class_name) {
   $class = explode("_", $class_name);
   $path = implode("/", $class).".php";
   require_once($path);
}
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
require_once('inc/autoload.php');
$core = new Core();
$core->run();
```

Comment: the classes exist under the `classes` folder, but you are trying to include from the current directory.

Comment: i created a config.php file under inc folder where i use set_include_path() function  and i call it first in the autoload.php file so no need to identify the classes folder i think its autometically identified

Comment: the error shows a list of all the include directories. Apparently it isn't including `classes` in that list. Are you loading the config file before all of this runs?

Comment: checked.i include the classes folder

Comment: Is this something you added after the question? I ask because the error specifically says `include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR'`. I don't see `classes` in there. Perhaps you should update the error if it has changed.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's a bit late. I was researching on this because I had the same problem. This is what i tried and it worked for me.

// this code is for the inc/autoload.php file.

```
define('__ROOT__', dirname(dirname(__FILE__)));
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . "/config.php");

//require_once(inc/config.php);


function __autoload($className){
$class = explode("_",$className);
$path = implode("/",$class).".php";
require_once($path);
```

}

Please I just started learning PHP and i stand corrected by you guys.
I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Core` class is apparently defined at:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\completed\classes\Core.php
```

But you attempt to load this file:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\completed\Core.php
```

It isn't a good idea to build a class auto-loader that works with relative paths*. I suggest you add a prefix here to build an absolute path:

```
 $path = implode("/", $class).".php";
```

E.g.:

```
 $path = __DIR__ . '/../classes/' . implode("/", $class).".php";
```

---

<sup>(*) Among other reasons, because relative paths in PHP are relative to the *main* script (rather than the file when path usage happens) so the source directory depends on what script you load `autoload.php` from.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

I've faced the same problem with yours. I think it's late for you. But may be it's helpful for others.

I **didn't** included the config.php file in autoload.php file

**inc/autoload.php**

```
//require_once('config.php');
```

I **included config.php file in the index.php** like this:

**index.php**

```
require_once('inc/config.php');
require_once('inc/autoload.php');
```

And it's worked fore me, I hope this for you, too :). Thanks for your time to read my comment.

Answer (score 0):

because in same folder

```
require_once('inc/autoload.php');

require_once('config.php');
```

so.. i think may be should like this

```
require_once('inc/config.php');
```